# Go to a specific address OllyDbg

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I have to go to a specific memory address in `OllyDbg`, and I can't find anything online (in this forum also).

How can I go to a specific address ?

So something that prompt me a window, that asks me for the address I want to go, also if this address is not in the `.text` section, but maybe into another section.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-G?

Comment: Yes, thanks man ! this works fine